# Resuming Fitting (particularly with NonlinearModelFit)

Tags: fitting

Assume I have some data to which I am fitting a curve. The curve is nonlinear, so I am using `NonlinearModelFit`. Let's assume I want to see the process of how a curve fits. Is there a good way to do that?

Would something along the lines of setting `MaxIterations` to 100 and then looking at the fit and then starting the fit again (initializing the values with the results from the first 100 iterations) work? Or are there intermediate values in the fitting process that will be lost?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`StepMonitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StepMonitor.html)

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x, 
  StepMonitor :> 
   Print["R^2 = ",
     1 - Total[(data[[All,  2]] - (Log[a + b x^2] 
     /. {x -> data[[All, 1]]}))^2]/ Total[(data[[All, 2]] - Mean[data[[All, 2]]])^2]]]
```